# nsupdate permission on records with windows DNS

Tags: windows, active-directory, nsupdate

I manage to play with nsupdate and active directory DNS server.

But my main problem is when I update the zone with authenticated users with this command :

```
nsupdate -g
```

It works, But next to the change, only the user who created the record can delete it update it...

Permissions are good on the zone side (allow any authenticated users)

But I don't know how to manage the update like when you tick the box "Allow any athenticated user to update all DNS records with the same name."

Or setting a kind of umask when the object is create to be able to change it with another user...

Someone got an idea on how to keep authenticated updated and set right permission at the same time ? Any workaround is also welcome :)

Comment: It seems that the problem comes from right update from DNS service (maybe zone refresh) will keep this question updated if it comes back.